# d3js: time scaling and "1901"

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working with a time-based scatterplot and am using data which only parses times by month, hour and day.  On my axis labels, I'm getting "1901".  D3 seems to be choosing a year and displaying it.  How can I easily get rid of this?  I don't want any year displayed:

[1901 example http://lmnts.lmnarchitects.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/2014-04-01-09_31_30-127.0.0.1_8020_Climate3_seattle-winter-temps.html.jpg](http://lmnts.lmnarchitects.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/2014-04-01-09_31_30-127.0.0.1_8020_Climate3_seattle-winter-temps.html.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set the [`tickFormat`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-tickFormat) of your axis to display only months and days. The `tickFormat` receives a function that takes a date and returns a string. You can use [`d3.time.format`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting) to set the tick format:

```
var axis = d3.svg.axis()
    // ... set more attributes
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%b %d'));  // Abbreviated month and decimal day (Apr 01)
```

Regards,

Comment: Thanks Pablo, it's working but there is a typo in than answer: d3.format needs to be d3.time.format.