# d3js: time scaling and winter months

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a scatter plot in d3js which isolates winter months.  Is there a quick and easy way to format the x scale such that I do not have a gap in the graph from March to December?  I'd prefer the x axis to range from December 21 to March 21:

[1901 example http://lmnts.lmnarchitects.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/2014-04-01-09_31_30-127.0.0.1_8020_Climate3_seattle-winter-temps.html.jpg](http://lmnts.lmnarchitects.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/2014-04-01-09_31_30-127.0.0.1_8020_Climate3_seattle-winter-temps.html.jpg)

Comment: possible duplicate of [d3js: time scaling and "1901"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22791741/d3js-time-scaling-and-1901)

Comment: It's not.  It's the same interface but I wanted to separate the questions.

Comment: My apologies, the questions are different. I retracted my vote.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your dates to have a year, even if you don't want it shown, assigning the months after July the previous year than the months of the first semester:

```
var data = [
   {date: '2012/12/01', RH: 50, ...},
   {date: '2012/12/02', RH: 55, ...},
   ...
   {date: '2013/03/31', RH: 89, ...}
];
```

And use `d3.extent` to set the extents of the date scale. The axis should show a continuous interval between December to March. Regards,